# trying to create a autoclick script

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hello im currently working on a website that has a third party chat box plugin. The application has no timer control on the pop up out of the box so id like to try and simulate a click on the chat button to make it appear sooner then the default timer.

The button is on the bottom right corner of this website: https://familyoffices.com/

The code im trying to hit is:
(this code gets generated from a script provided from the plugin)

```
<iframe id="iframe-designstudio-button- 
style="border:none;display:block;" name="designstudio-button- 
frame" title="Live Chat Button" scrolling="no" class="iframe-button- 
text" height="34" width="113"></iframe>
<html class="wf-droidsans-n4- 
 active wf-active"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device- 
 width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"> 
<title>Live Chat Button</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400" 
media="all"> <style type="text/css"></style> 
</head> <body> 
<div id="iframe-button-container" style="height: 34px; width: 
 113.265625px;">
<div id="iframe-button-content" class="button-text" 
 style="bottom: 0px; right: 0px;"> 
<span id="designstudio-button- 
text">Chat with us..</span>
</div> </div> </body> </html>
```

I used this Javascript but i couldnt get it to work.

```
 (this is above the body)
  <script>
 function haveclicked(){
 document.getElementById('iframe-designstudio- 
 button').contentWindow.document.getElementById('iframe-button- 
 container').trigger('click');
  }
 </script>

 <body data-rsssl="1" onload="setTimeout('haveclicked();',3000);"
```

Does anyone have any idea how i can do this?

Comment: <body data-rsssl="1" onload="setTimeout('haveclicked',3000);">

just add the function name you don't need `()`

Comment: i just tried this. Didnt work

Comment: should the last `-` not be a `"` in `<iframe id="iframe-designstudio-button-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.click()` rather than `.trigger('click')`. `.trigger` is a jQuery method, but you're referencing the built-in object, so use the appropriate built-in method instead:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('iframe-designstudio-button')
    .contentWindow.document.getElementById('iframe-button-container').click();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: how do i place this on the page? above the body in a <script> tag?

Comment: Sure, put it wherever you want, as long as it runs

Comment: <script>
  setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('iframe-designstudio-button')
    .contentWindow.document.getElementById('iframe-button-container').click();
}, 1000);
 </script>

?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use ..

```
window.frames['iframe-designstudio-button'].contentWindow.document.getElementById("designstudio-button-text").click();
```

to open chat window.

```
 <script>
 function haveclicked(){
  window.frames['iframe-designstudio-button'].contentWindow.document.getElementById("designstudio-button-text").click();
  }
 </script>

 <body data-rsssl="1" onload="setTimeout('haveclicked();',3000);"
```

Comment: sorry i just tried this and it didnt work on the site

Comment: @Tetzuro missed the reading iframe part. Try now its working.

Comment: ah yes this method is working too! thank you brother! you have saved me a job haha